# Sailsjs: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: javascript, websocket, sails.js, csrf

Sails 1 version giving below error and redirecting back to login screen when tried to login instead of taking to welcome page.

> 400 Bad Request

```
ws://xyz.com/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=1.2.1&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket
```

One more error:

> 403 Request Forbidden

Not able to register or login. Temporarily disabled csrf in `security.js` without finding the solution so far.

Has anybody faced such issue, and may i know if this fix is possible from application level or do we need to modify apache settings?

Comment: Have you looked at [sails.config.sockets.onlyAllowOrigins](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment#?set-a-sailsconfigsocketsonlyalloworigins-value) and [sails.config.security.allowOrigins](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-security#?properties)?

Comment: That is been configured with i.e `baseUrl` http://example.com. Should i add ws://xyz.com along with it

Comment: If suppose i try to add: ws:// to the socket allowOnlyOriginis list, i receive an error: `Failed to lift app: Error: Must specify a protocol like http:// or https://`

Answer (score 0):

> By adding below code inside apache configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:1337/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:1337/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1337/
```

**The problem was resolved**

After doing the changes in the config file run the below command to check the syntax of apache.

`httpd -t`

After the syntax is correct use the below command to restart apache

`service httpd restart`